# Mark binaries writable and executable in openBSD

Tags: executable, openbsd

As of OpenBSD 6.0 mandatory W^X enforcement is implemented.

Binaries that need permission to violate this rule can be marked with the ld command:

> Identify W^X labelled binaries at execve(2) time based upon the WX_OPENBSD_WXNEEDED flag set by ld -zwxneeded.

I tried:

```
    ld -b <binary> -zwxneeded
    ld <binary> -zwxneeded

    # ld -b sbcl -zwxneeded
    ld: no input files
    # ld sbcl -zwxneeded    
    sbcl: could not read symbols: File format not recognized
```

I've been reading the ld man page but can't figure out the right syntax for file I/O to set the required flag. Any help/advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/308179/edit) your question to include the errors you're getting.

Comment: Done, trying to mark any binary in /usr/local/bin gives the listed errors.

Comment: What is the original problem you have? You are probably picking a wrong tool to solve it.

Comment: The [man page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/ld.1) says "`ld` [ *options* ] *objfile* ..." — have you tried `ld -zwxneeded sbcl`? (I assume that "`sbcl`" is your file name. It would be nice if you would mention things like that, so we wouldn't need to guess.)

Comment: ld is used as linker but is able to flag binaries too as mentioned in openBSD changelog https://www.openbsd.org/plus60.html, sbcl is the binary file I want to flag

Comment: @G-Man I tried ld -zwxneeded <file> but it gives the 'file format not recognized' error as mentioned above

Comment: I understand it that `-zwxneeded` will mark binaries to need W^X. When you search in changes document, you'll also find the remark that you can mount the fs where the binary resides with option `wxallowed`.

Comment: @polymechanos What do you mean by “able to flag binaries”? I'm no OpenBSD expert, but generally `ld` builds an executable, it doesn't modify an existing executable, and I don't see anything in the OpenBSD changelog that suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer after rereading openBSD upgrade guide, filesystem mount options have to be adjusted in fstab.

> The wxallowed mount option. W^X is now strictly enforced by default; a program can only violate it if it is located on a filesystem mounted with the wxallowed mount(8) option. This allows the base system to be more secure as long as /usr/local is a separate filesystem.
>
> The base system has no W^X-violating programs, but the ports tree contains quite a few: chromium, mono, node, gnome, libreoffice, jdk, zeal, etc. If you want to run any of these ports on a regular basis, you need to add wxallowed to the mount options for /usr/local in fstab(5), e.g.:

```
  01020304050607.h /usr/local ffs rw,nodev,wxallowed 1 2
```

> Small disks may not have a separate partition for /usr/local. In that case, add wxallowed to the smallest partition containing it: /usr or /.
>
> Starting a W^X-violating program from a partition without the wxallowed mount option will produce a core dump and the dmesg(8) will contain an entry such as soffice.bin(15529): mprotect W^X violation. You can temporarily allow W^X-violating ports by issuing mount -uo wxallowed /usr/local.